# Migrate to a new iCloud plan from current Family Sharing plan

Tags: icloud, storage, family-sharing

I am currently on a Family Sharing plan (2TB) but need to move to my own plan. On my Mac, when I click on "Add Storage", it prompts me saying that, when I change my storage plan, I will stop using the family one.

However, I do want to ensure that all my data moves to the new storage. Does anyone know if Apple takes care of this automatically, if I proceed. Or do I need to backup all my data somewhere (external HDD)?